# Taking value from column in one sqlite3 table and inserting into another

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to add a feature to my program where a teacher sets homework to users from a class they've made. There is a table for users where each user has a unique UserID, classname, firstname and surname. I am trying to take the userIDs of students who are in a certain class, and insert them into a HomeworkSet table. I am able to retrieve the userIDs successfully, but when I insert them into the HomeworkSet table, the values appear as (for example) ('2a1910e919a84230bfc2a7111160cade',), and I am not sure how I am meant to remove the brackets and apostraphes.

```
def Class_sethw():
        homeworktoset = Homework_To_Set.get()
        #print (homeworktoset)
        conn = sqlite3.connect('MyComputerScience.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        homeworkID = c.execute("SELECT HWID FROM HomeworkInfo WHERE HomeworkName = ?", (homeworktoset, )).fetchone()
        print (homeworkID)
        c.execute("SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE ClassName = ?", (ClassName_SetHWR, ))
        homeworksetlist = c.fetchall()
        print (homeworksetlist)
        for i in (homeworksetlist):
            #x = i
            #firstname, lastname = x.split(" ")
            c.execute('insert INTO HomeworkSet (HWID, StudentID)VALUES(?,?);', ((homeworkID[0]), str(i)))
            conn.commit()
            Label(sethw, text = "Homework Set!", fg = "GREEN").place(relx=0.205, rely=0.445, height=34, width=97)
```

This is the code I have used.

Comment: which variable appears as `('2a1910e919a84230bfc2a7111160cade',)`? to me that just looks like what a typical cursor returns

Comment: homeworksetlist returns that value

Comment: so where exactly is the issue then? sounds like your iteration takes care of unpacking it properly

Comment: I'm trying to remove the brackets and apostrophe for when it is inserted into the next table HomeworkSet

Comment: chnage `for i in (homeworksetlist)` to `for i in homeworksetlist`

Answer (score 0):

You should change this line:

```
for i in (homeworksetlist):
```

to:

```
for i in homeworksetlist:
```